# Preventing GUI hangs in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous, c++-cli

I am relatively new to C# WPF projects and I have an issue with my code whereby the user interface "locks up" whilst I am running a task. Here is the relevant code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    // handles to ManagedDLAContainer objects
    private ManagedDLA2DContainer dla_2d;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        // initalise aggregate containers
        dla_2d = new ManagedDLA2DContainer();
    }

    private void GenerateAggregate() {
        // generate the 2D aggregate of size given by particles_slider value
        Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { dla_2d.Generate((uint)particles_slider.Value); }));

        // TODO: add particles to "canvas" on GUI as they are generated
    }

    private void GenerateButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        // set the coefficient of stickiness of aggregate
        // to current value of stickiness_slider
        dla_2d.SetCoeffStick(stickiness_slider.Value);

        // start asynchronous task calling GenerateAggregate method
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => GenerateAggregate());
    }

}
```

Here `ManagedDLA2DContainer` is a managed `C++/CLI` wrapper for some native, unmanaged `C++` code and `stickiness_slider` is simply a `Slider` element of the WPF interface; whilst, similarly, `particles_slider` is another Slider element of the interface. I should note that the following code also results in the GUI hanging:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {

    // lock object for multi-threading tasks
    private static readonly object locker = new object();

    // handles to ManagedDLAContainer objects
    private ManagedDLA2DContainer dla_2d;

    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        // initalise aggregate containers
        dla_2d = new ManagedDLA2DContainer();
    }

    private void GenerateAggregate() {
        // lock around aggregate generation
        lock (locker) {
            // generate the 2D aggregate of size given by particles_slider value
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => { dla_2d.Generate((uint)particles_slider.Value); }));

            // TODO: add particles to "canvas" on GUI as they are generated
        }
    }

    private void GenerateButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        // set the coefficient of stickiness of aggregate
        // to current value of stickiness_slider
        dla_2d.SetCoeffStick(stickiness_slider.Value);

        Thread agg_gen_thread = new Thread(GenerateAggregate);
        agg_gen_thread.Start();
        agg_gen_thread.Join();
    }

}
```

Any information which could help me understand what I might be doing wrong here is appreciated.

Also, if you are curious then all the code for this project is available here: https://github.com/SJR276/DLAProject

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start new thread in which you run `GenerateAggregate`. Then immediatly you dispatch all work *back* to user interface thread via `Dispatcher.Invoke`. So basically you are running long running task on UI thread and it blocks.

Instead, you should dispatch to UI thread only operations that require that (which update UI controls for example), not the whole operation.

Suppose your Generate function looks like this:

```
void Generate() {
  MakeCpuIntensiveWork();
  UpdateUIWithResults();
}
```

You only need to dispatch second part to UI thread. In your case, as we found out in comments, the only UI part is getting value of a slider. So you can split like this:

```
private void GenerateAggregate()
{
    uint sliderValue = 0;
    // generate the 2D aggregate of size given by particles_slider value
    Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { sliderValue = (uint)particles_slider.Value; });
    dla_2d.Generate(sliderValue);
    // TODO: add particles to "canvas" on GUI as they are generated
}
```

Comment: Without `Dispatcher.Invoke` I will get a run-time exception stating that the calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. Also, `GenerateAggregate` will be adding items to the GUI (eventually) so it is in my understanding that I require use of `Dispatch.Invoke`.

Comment: You need to Dispatch _only_ parts which update UI controls, not the whole method.

Comment: Ah, I see, that makes sense. I should note - `Generate` is a method of the `ManagedDLA2DContainer` class which is C++/CLI code; is it actually possible to update the UI from the C++/CLI wrapper?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. If that is C++\CLI method, I suppose you are not updating UI inside it (at least not WPF controls)? If not - just run it without dispatcher, and dispatch only the rest of your GenerateAggregate function to UI thread (that rest part is not shown in your example as I understand).

Comment: Yes currently `Generate` only executes a C++ method from the `DLAClassLibrary`. However, even though it is not altering the GUI at the moment, removing `Dispatcher.Invoke` will still result in the run-time exception mentioned previously. Maybe it's due to accessing the `particles_slider` element?

Comment: Yes if particles_slider is UI control then that is the reason (was not obvious from code only). So make separate function which returns value of this slider (or use anonymous functions) and wrap only this one in Dispatcher.Invoke, then call your wrapper as usual (outside Dispatcher.Invoke).